# Do Chrome Dev Tools support flexbox CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, flexbox

When inspecting the elements with block style here, CDT shows the height property as dimmed:
   http://s.codepen.io/WhitneyLand/debug/zGpZbN

[image: dimmed height property]

The docs say dimmed means inherited property that is not affecting the element, however clearly the height value is inherited, but is affecting the element.

So, how are we supposed to trace the source of a style like this using CDT?

```
/* full example http://s.codepen.io/WhitneyLand/debug/zGpZbN */
<div class="block block-fixed">
    aaa
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. It does support.

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal citation relating to my posted code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is occurring because that height is calculated from the contents of the `div`. Namely, the 'aaa' text. Adding a `font-size: 40px;` to the `.block-fixed` class grows the calculated height to 47px. In this case it's dimmed because it's calculated.

Comment: That's not what the docs say dimmed should mean though?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6351378/700206   Also, how are you supposed to derive what you said from CDT, rather than just knowing?

Comment: @LeeWhitney Docs where just updated: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/devtools-docs/commit/d1903ffc30a80a2801fe3339ac779e96abd66243

Answer (score 1):

The `height` you are seeing is a `computed` style property (computed via the browser's rendering engine), not a declared/inherited one. You'll notice when you hover over the total element in the DOM inspector, the "height" of the div is 19px - 18px tall and 1px bottom border.

Comment: Read closer - inherited properties are only displayed in a dimmed font **when the show inherited box is checked** - the `height` property displays in a dimmed font without that box being checked. In addition to all that, nowhere in your CSS is a height of 18px being applied, so it can't be `inherited`. It's a computed property (by the browser) that hasn't been specified in CSS.

Comment: I will concede that nowhere in the dev tool docs (that I have come across) explain this behaviour, but there's nothing else it could possibly mean, so it's a pretty straightforward inference.

Comment: CSS is tough for me with precise tool documentation.  I think reading the entire spec end to end would help solidify it.

Comment: Reading the entire CSS spec will help you very little - having a basic understanding, and then using it and seeing how it works with your own eyes will solidify it far better.

Comment: I updated the docs to help clarify this. please pull-request if this isnt' good enough: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/devtools-docs/commit/d1903ffc30a80a2801fe3339ac779e96abd66243